# converting csvhelper list into a dictionary<string, object>

Tags: c#, arrays, csv, sorting, csvhelper

I have a csv file that looks like this:

```
23.75,-71.14026637566099,23.26,-68.14,X (mm),Y (mm),X (mm),Y (mm),X (mm),Y (mm)
75.0,0.0,72.0,0.0,-70.8744,-11.0272,-62.1812,-22.0121,1.1013,5.3621
74.62531239585194,7.487506248512112,71.64029990001787,7.188005998571628,-66.1987,26.7792,-61.3198,24.1895,5.8892,34.9479
73.50499333809312,14.90019980962959,70.5647936045694,14.304191817244408,-54.6861,21.1036,-60.9723,-29.1698,,
71.65023668442045,22.16401549960047,68.78422721704364,21.27745487961645,-53.3795,20.8321,-57.5484,-7.0754,,
69.07957455021638,29.206375673148788,66.31639156820773,28.038120646222836,-44.5103,16.9127,-50.7663,34.2947,,
65.81869214177796,35.95691539531523,63.18594445610684,34.518638779502616,,,-48.7116,52.8106,,
61.90017111822588,42.34818550462765,59.42416427349683,40.65425808444255,,,-39.5089,41.8543,,
57.363164046336635,48.31632654282683,55.06863748448316,46.38367348111376,,,-38.6843,-45.1223,,
52.253003201037416,53.8017068174642,50.16288307299591,51.649638544765644,,,-37.7029,40.9664,,
46.62074762029984,58.74951822206125,44.75591771548784,56.399537493178805,,,-36.1945,7.7452,,
40.52267294011048,63.11032386059223,38.90176602250607,60.58591090616855,,,-33.1654,-12.0199,,
34.01970910691831,66.84055200460764,32.65892074264157,64.16692992442336,,,-27.4216,65.4545,,
27.17683158575052,69.90293144754197,26.089758322320485,67.1068141896403,,,-26.9546,-27.5354,,
20.06241214684405,72.26686390628947,19.25991566097029,69.37618935003789,,,-25.4676,24.2481,,
12.747535717518062,73.90872974913452,12.237634288817338,70.95238055916914,,,-19.3518,-53.9162,,
5.305290125077701,74.81212399530408,5.093078520074609,71.81963903549192,,,-15.8018,36.0254,,
-2.1899641725966776,74.96802022811288,-2.102365605692795,71.96929941898837,,,-12.8175,26.027,,
-9.663337072164381,74.37486078393515,-9.27680358927779,71.39986635257773,,,-12.8157,33.5647,,
-17.040157101981563,73.03857231586463,-16.358550817902273,70.11702942323005,,,-12.6135,14.0177,,
-24.246717514762796,70.97250657655607,-23.276848814172258,68.13360631349384,,,-12.5522,44.1962,,
-31.21101274103571,68.19730701192611,-29.962572231394255,65.46941473144908,,,-11.0237,4.4988,,
-37.86345784498934,64.74070249866551,-36.34891953118974,62.151074398718904,,,-11.014,15.0086,,
```

Getting this data is not a problem for me, here is my working code.

```
 class CsvHelperTester
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var config = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
            {
                HasHeaderRecord = false,
                MissingFieldFound = null,
                ShouldSkipRecord = args => args.Row.Parser.Record.All(String.IsNullOrEmpty)
            };

            using (var reader = new StreamReader("C:\\Users\\eyoung\\Desktop\\parse test files\\Data.csv"))
            using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, config))
            {
                var SicaGraphData = new List<SicaGraphData>();

                while (csv.Read())
                {
                    SicaGraphData.Add(csv.GetRecord<SicaGraphData>());
                }

            }
        }

        public class SicaGraphData
        {
            public string Value1 { get; set; }
            public string Value2 { get; set; }
            public string Value3 { get; set; }
            public string Value4 { get; set; }
            [Name("X (mm)")]
            public string X { get; set; }
            [Name("Y (mm)")]
            public string Y { get; set; }
            [Name("X2 (mm)")]
            public string X2 { get; set; }
            [Name("Y2 (mm)")]
            public string Y2 { get; set; }
            [Name("X3 (mm)")]
            public string X3 { get; set; }
            [Name("Y3 (mm)")]
            public string Y3 { get; set; }
        }
        
    }
```

What I want to do is convert this lost list into a dictionary, like List<Dictionary<string,object>> So the data needs to be converted into horizontal data, like this:

```
Y(mm) : -61.232543
Y2(mm) : 63.23532
```

However, I'm not sure how to do this type of conversion or if there is a better solution. I have no control over this csv, so this is just how it will come to me. I don't even know if the data can be converted into the dictionary that I need. I need the data converted into this format, as I'm going to convert this data into a datatable and send it to MongoDB, so it can be read nicely. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: This seems like a step backwards from well-defined fields in a class.

Comment: Have you tried `csv.GetRecord<Dictionary<string,object>>()` already?

Comment: Yes I have tried that, the conversion isn't that easy, although I wish it was. @GoodNightNerdPride

Comment: Some serializers support that. But I agree with @JoelCoehoorn that it seems wrong to user `object` when you have a well-defined type. Are you sure MongoDB only accepts `Dictionary`s?

Comment: I can do this very easily but need to know more about the file.  You only posted one sample of the data.  You should use number instead of string.  What is the difference between the first row and the other rows.  What value do you want to be the key of the dictionary.  It looks like each row has multiple X & Y values.  Ths data looks like a polygon with first row being one corner of the polygon and the other points being the corners of the poly.  Are there more than one poly in the file.  How do you know where each poly starts.

Comment: All of the data in our mongo databases are 2 column datatables, but those datatables are being made from dictionaries<string, object> @GoodNightNerdPride

Comment: @jdweng this is the only sample I have, this is the exact file they gave me. As I said, if there is a better solution, then by all means, go for it. The Multiple x y values are points on a graph, x1 and y1 are one type of point, x2 and y2 are a different type of point on the graph. Not polygons, sorry for the confusion

Comment: To sort properly you need a number, not a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be done using reflection. Just stating that reflection will be slower than writing out the conversion from the SicaGraphData class to a dictionary but thought this is a good use case for show casing how it works.

The code is just an example, checking properties and values using reflection can be a little bit trickier if you create complex classes or using generics.

I've created two approaches. The first to convert the data into the output based on the question. This approach really doesn't need reflection, you can easily write a method to map a row to a dictionary.
This is a simple map/select function.

```
        public static List<Dictionary<string, object?>> PivotRecord(List<SicaGraphData> data){
            return data.Select(row => MapToDictionary(row)).ToList();
        }

         private static Dictionary<string, object?> MapToDictionary(SicaGraphData row) {
            var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, object?>(){};
            foreach(var prop in row.GetType().GetProperties()) {
                var cellValue = prop.GetValue(row, null);
                dictionary.Add(prop.Name, cellValue);
            }
            return dictionary;
        }
```

The second variance converting the data into a dictionary with a list of values. This can be seen as a Reduce function.

```
        public static Dictionary<string, List<object?>> PivotDataSet(List<SicaGraphData> data){
            var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, List<object?>>();
            var properties = typeof(SicaGraphData).GetProperties();
            foreach(var row in data) {
                foreach(var prop in properties) {
                    var cellValue = prop.GetValue(row, null);
                    if (dictionary.TryGetValue(prop.Name, out var list)) {
                        list.Add(cellValue);
                    } else {
                        dictionary.Add(prop.Name, new List<object?>(){ cellValue});
                    }
                }
            }
            return dictionary;
        }
```

Comment: Maybe a dumb question, but how can I print the results of the first solution to the console? @PaulSalmon

Comment: It returns an array so you would need to loop through each record and then console.log each row. Dictionaries is slightly easier to print out than classes with properties. You can iterate through a dictionary as a KeyValue pair. foreach(var keyValue in dictionary) {  Console.WriteLine($"{keyValue.Key}:{keyValue.Value}"); }